# Fanned out cards in WPF- performance issues

Tags: wpf, performance, controls, overlapping

In my WPF app I have a control representing a pack of 20 cards (each about 150x80 px) that fan out in an arc, so they're all slightly overlapping in the centre of the arc. When the control is added there's an animation to fan them out.

After that, the fan/control can be moved around, and when the user hovers over a card it expands and then goes back to normal size when they move off it.

This all works fine, but has a noticeable effect on performance- everything is very jerky, presumably because when other things move all the overlapping stuff and transforms in the control are being constantly recalculated/redrawn.

Any suggestions for how I can improve performance while still keeping individual cards in the fan responsive?

Comment: Try getting hold of the Expression Blend v2 or v3 - that came with a sample application which included fanning out cards (actually color swabs, but close enough). If I remember, they animated smoothly, so try copying that.

Comment: Thanks Schneider, I'll check that out. Just to clarify though: the animations I have now are smooth enough, it's other aspects of performance that suffer. For instance, dragging other simple images or controls is much jerkier when the card control is present but nice and smooth when it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the source of the slowdown you need to profile.

Try to find out whether or not WPF is [switching back to software rendering or not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx#perforator).

After that try to run on a different computer with other (better) hardware/graphics card.

If it doesn't get any better there might be errors in your app.